# .not() isn't working properly for me

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to make a menu where it will stay open for so long and then fades if the parent or the menu is not hovered over for a given period of time.

If you highlight over another parent in the menu the idea is it closes all other menus except for the parent you're already on. The code as it stands keeps all menus open instead of closing all but the one you have highlighted

The Menu

```
$text .=            '<div class="dropdown">';
$text .=                '<a href="/products">Products</a>';
$text .=                '<div class="menu-popup">';
$text .=                '</div>';
$text .=            '</div>';

$text .=            '<div class="dropdown">';
$text .=                '<a href="/about">About</a>';
$text .=                '<div class="menu-popup">';
$text .=                '</div>';
$text .=            '</div>';
```

The Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(".dropdown").mouseover(function() {
       //Highlighting over the parent "dropdown" closes all other popup menus & 
       //displays the popup related to the parent
       $(".menu-popup").not(this).find(".menu-popup").hide();
       $(this).find(".menu-popup").fadeIn("fast");

       //Reset the timer to hide popup if scrolling back over parent
       //before time runs out
       if (hideTimer !== null) {
           clearTimeout(hideTimer);
       }
    });

    //Scrolling off of the dropdown parent will set a timer that will 
    //hide the menu-popup
    $(".dropdown").bind("mouseout", function(){
        hideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".menu-popup").fadeOut("fast");
     }, 300);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Might be `$(".menu-popup").not($(this).find(".menu-popup")).hide();`

Comment: @Satpal $(".dropdown").not(this).find(".menu-popup").hide(); would be easier.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, I have not fully understood question thus `Might be`. Yep its seems ^^^^ that would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `$(this)` refers to `drop-down` and not `menu-popup`. So you need to find `menu-popup` inside `drop-down` but not inside current `drop-down`.

change this

```
$(".menu-popup").not(this).find(".menu-popup").hide();
```

to

```
 $(".dropdown").not(this).find(".menu-popup").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop and Satpal :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `not()` altogether, you're fading in the one you need afterward, so just hide them all.

```
$(".menu-popup").hide();
$(this).find(".menu-popup").fadeIn("fast");
```

Comment: Sorry I feel this is the wrong answer because if I were to hover over the parent that already has the popup activated it would make the popup flicker dude to hiding then fading in again.

Comment: Wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/DcJZk/ The only time the code is run is when you're entering the box in the first place, so there's no situation where the code will run and hide a box that was already being shown and then fade it back in.

Comment: @Dom I just realised you have a 300 millisecond delay on fading them out, so I guess technically there's a 300 millisecond window where what you're describing could theoretically happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply recommend to use like this:

```
$(".menu-popup").hide();//first hide all menu-popup
$(this).find(".menu-popup").fadeIn("fast"); //display this menu-popup only
```